# What is the best time interval in condition monitoring programs for checking rolling bearings?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration, mechanical-failure

The time intervals between observing or measuring the vibration of rolling bearings in industrial plants are so important in condition monitoring programs. For instance, some experts measure the vibration once a month, and others measure it once every two weeks.

How can we determine it?

Is there any ISO standard?

Comment: In critical applications (e.g. jet engines) it is monitored continuously whenever the engine is running.

Comment: Based on mtbf, running speed as a fraction of max permitted, load, working temperature, lubrication and cooling. Also based on the engineer's experience and even the use of a stethoscope to evaluate condition. At least that was what I discussed with the paper mill engineer years ago.

Answer (score 2):

**I know of no global standards for vibration monitoring.**

Like all preventive/predictive maintenance items, these things need to be equipment-specific.  These are the same considerations you would apply to any preventive checks, including autonomous maintenance checks. Considerations include:

- process impacts (Loss of production)
- equipment failure cost
- installed back-up availability
- likelihood of failure during interval (for example, a 3600 rpm motor is much more failure-prone than a 1200 rpm motor)
- resources available for monitoring - people, money, and equipment

All the above can be applied to standard monitoring with a portable device, to hooking up to permanent transducers, or to continuous monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring has been continuous for over 30 years in critical equipment in petrochemicals. Our rotating machinery guy liked to do it in two directions; Something about rotor swirl which helped him to predict. There must be substantial info some where .

Comment: if you have the resources to do it continuously that would be an input

Comment: "rotor swirl" or "rotor whirl"? I don't know about your "two directions" comment, but IMO forwards whirl of rotors just wears things out very fast, but reverse whirl often makes a loud bang and a pile of broken bits, with very little warning!

Comment: Swirl , The center of large turbine shafts wanders ( a little) in a regular pattern . Can't remember the name of the affect.  Not my job, but was impressed  walking through the motor  stator  of an axial flow air compressor  ( Dresser built but the design was German) , the motor shaft was 14 in. diameter ; pardon old guy rambling.